# Ext JS Form with Filefield Always Triggers Error on Submission

Tags: javascript, asp.net, extjs

I'm using Ext JS to create a form that submits data to a .NET 7 API. Initially, when I submitted the form without a filefield, it responded successfully with {"success":true,"messages":"create vehicle abc025 successfully","total":1}.

However, after adding a filefield to the form:

```
    xtype: 'filefield',
    name: 'photofile',
    fieldLabel: 'Image',
    labelWidth: 50,
    width: '300px',
    itemId: 'imagefield_vehicle',
    msgTarget: 'side',
    anchor: '100%',
    buttonText: 'Select Image...',
    accept: 'image/*',
```

the form submission behaves inconsistently. Although the backend processes the request and saves data to the database normally, the form submission always triggers the failure callback. In the network tab, sometimes it shows a response similar to before, and other times it shows nothing. Regardless of the backend's success, the failure callback displays the following error message:
`"{"success":false,"message":"Failed to read a named property 'document' from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin \"http://localhost:3000\" from accessing a cross-origin frame."}"`

for more information
Here's my form submission code:

```
form.submit({
   url: url,
   params: {
     skills: skill,
     createDate: Admin.shared.util.Utilities.getCurrentDateInFormat(),
     createBy: "string",
        },
   success: function (xform, res) {
      Ext.MessageBox.show({
      title: "Message",
      msg: "<br/>" + res.result.messages,
      buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
      fn: function () {                                                 
         Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#vehicle-create-window')[0].close()                                                    
         store.loadPage(store.currentPage)
      },
      icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO, });
   },
   failure: function (xform, res) {
   console.log(res)},
```

both case this submit are not change only change is comment or uncomment it

I also has Cors and has app.UseCors

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});
```

Why does adding a filefield cause this cross-origin frame access error, and how can I resolve it?

Use Ext js submit with image in form